# loop nested conditions are overwritten by data

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a JSON file with objects like:

```
  {
        "id": 23,
        "active": true,
        "state": "on",
        "dependency": [
            {
                "id": 24,
                "type": "critical"
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "type": "moderate"
            },
            {
                "id": 25,
                "type": "critical"
            },
            {
                "id": 35,
                "type": "moderate" 
            }
        ]
    },
```

The dependency value is unordered and will be filled from other functions. This order isn´t sorted. Further the type of the dependencies "choose" the root SVG object color. Critical will be red[error] and moderate will be yellow[limited] .

The loop works, if all "moderate" entries stay at the bottom. As soon as the list is mixed, like in the example above. The state will be never "limited", because it gets overwritten by "error".

I created a proof boolean which should avoid such case but each console.log teach me better. Any idea, I am almost blind about.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    isModerate = false
    if (graph.nodes[i].active === true && graph.nodes[i].dependency.length == 0)  {
        graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
    } else if (graph.nodes[i].active === true && graph.nodes[i].dependency.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < graph.nodes[i].dependency.length; j++) {
            if (graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].type === "critical") {
                if (!isModerate && graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "on") {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
                } else if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "limited" || "error" || "off") {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "error"
                    break
                }
            } else if (graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].type === "moderate") {
                if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "on" ) {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
                } else if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "limited" || "error" || "off" ) {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "limited"
                    isModerate = true
                }
            }
        }            
    } else if (graph.nodes[i].active === false) {
        graph.nodes[i].state = "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your goal. You want 4 states `on`, `off`, `limited` and `error`.  Please describe in words how you determine what triggers a state change. For example: If critical is found in any dependency, does it go to `error`? If moderate is found, but critical is not, then state is set to `limited`? Please clarify.

Comment: btw it would make your code much more readable if you declare a variable node=graph.nodes[I] instead of typing this term again and again. Same for dependency

Comment: Also if(state === "limited" || "error" || "off") is not a valid Javascript syntax. If you are trying to check whether state is among those option try if([ "limited", "error", "off"].includes(state))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rewrote it...trying to debug this is insane...

```js
for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    isModerate = false
    if (graph.nodes[i].active === true && graph.nodes[i].dependency.length == 0) {
        graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
    } else if (graph.nodes[i].active === true && graph.nodes[i].dependency.length > 0) {
        // ------------------------------
        // item in dependency lsit
        for (var j = 0; j < graph.nodes[i].dependency.length; j++) {
            if (graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].type === "critical") {
                if (!isModerate && graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "on") {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
                } else if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "limited" || "error" || "off") {
                    // ------------------------------
                    // you break at here
                    // so any remain items in the dependency will be skip/ignore
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "error"
                    break
                    // ------------------------------
                }
            } else if (graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].type === "moderate") {
                if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "on") {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "on"
                } else if (graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "limited" || "error" || "off") {
                    graph.nodes[i].state = "limited"
                    isModerate = true
                }
            }
        }
        // ------------------------------
    } else if (graph.nodes[i].active === false) {
        graph.nodes[i].state = "off"
    }
}
```

I only see 4 states
so whaterver you try to do with this

```
graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state === "limited" || "error" || "off"
```

is the same as this

```
graph.nodes[graph.nodes[i].dependency[j].id].state !== "on"
```

my best guess at what your code want to do and rewrote it...

```js
// I guess this is the structure...
let graph = {
    nodes: [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "active": true,
            "state": "on",
            "dependency": [
                { "id": 24, "type": "critical" },
                { "id": 30, "type": "moderate" },
                { "id": 25, "type": "critical" },
                { "id": 35, "type": "moderate" }
            ]
        },
    ],
};

const
    // use dictionary, so IDE can:
    // auto highlight/change it all/auto snippet for you & avoid typo
    // easier to track/change, try to replace string is messy
    state = {
        on: "on",
        limited: "limited",
        error: "error",
        off: "off",
    },
    type = {
        critical: "critical",
        moderate: "moderate",
    },
    // a function to get specific node's state
    getNodeState = (id) => {
        let node = graph.nodes.find(node => node.id == id);
        if (!node) {
            throw Error(`node id:${id} not found`);
        } else {
            return node.state;
        }
    };

graph.nodes.forEach(node => {
    let isModerate = false;

    if (node.active) {
        if (node.dependency.length === 0) {
            node.state = state.on;
        } else {
            node.dependency.forEach(dependency => {
                if (dependency.type == type.critical) {
                    if (!isModerate && (getNodeState(dependency.id) == state.on)) {
                        node.state = state.on;
                    } else if (node.state != state.on) {
                        // I only see 4 states, just revers it
                        node.state = state.error;
                        // no break here, it will continue to process all items in the dependency
                    }
                } else if (dependency.type == type.moderate) {
                    if (getNodeState(dependency.id) == state.on) {
                        node.state = state.on;
                    } else if (node.state != state.on) {
                        node.state = state.limited;
                        isModerate = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        node.state = state.off;
    }
});
```